# Problem making timestamp out of date received from a dropdown select menu.

Tags: php, codeigniter, date

I want to only allow visitors to choose from certain dates, for example the next 20 days. So I have a form which looks like this.

```
<select name="data">
<?php
    $day = date('d');
    $i = 1;
    while($i < 20) {
        $i++;
        $data = (date("d-M-Y",mktime(0,0,0,7,$day,2011)) . "<br />");
        echo "<option value='".$data."'>".$data."</option>";
        $day++;
    }
?>
</select>
```

In the controller (I use Code Igniter), I can echo the date but I cannot make a timestamp out of the date.

```
$data = $this->input->post('data');
$timestamp = strtotime('$data');
echo $timestamp;
```

The `echo $timestamp` doesn't work. It displays nothing.

My `$date` is `23-08-2011` However, `echo strtotime('23-08-2011');` works.

I even tried it outside of Code Igniter (1 form, 1 processformfile) and it still doesn't work.

Do you have any ideas why it doesn't work?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: What-if it's the year 2012, or even another month? Does your code still work?

Comment: CodeIgniter has a config option for date formatting which you might want to use.  In your case, it would look like `date($this->config->item('log_date_format'), mktime(0, 0, 0, 7, $day, 2011))` if you were to use it.

Comment: Thanx Chris.@pindatjuh.It wasn't the final code just a test.I have $month in the mktime function ,where $month=date('m');It works for any year.

Answer (score 4):

Well, `$timestamp=strtotime('$data');` wouldn't work because you're treating `$data` as a literal string. Remove the quotes:

```
$timestamp=strtotime($data);
```

Also, you're setting `$data` as a formatted string with a line break:

```
$data=(date("d-M-Y",mktime(0,0,0,7,$day,2011))."<br />");
```

Try:

```
$data=date("d-M-Y",mktime(0,0,0,7,$day,2011);
```

Comment: Or use double-quotes `"$data"`.

Comment: Thanks a lot.I hope I win Most Stupid Question of 2011 award.@AlienWebguy.cool avatar :)

Comment: Glad to help. Please make sure you click the check mark next to my answer if it helped you. Thanks!